# How to get latest value of a field on a related model in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset, annotate

I have the following models:

```
class Timestamped(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Thread(Timestamped):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user1')
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user2')

class Message(Timestamped):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I have a QuerySet to get all threads, but I also want to display the latest message for each thread while I loop over them.

I have come up with the following to show the latest Timestamp for the message.

```
threads = Thread.objects.filter(Q(user1=request.user) | Q(user2=request.user))\
            .annotate(latest_msg=Max('message__modified')).order_by('-latest_msg')
```

How can I show the message text?

Answer (score 2):

```
threads = Thread.objects.filter(
            Q(user1=request.user) | Q(user2=request.user)
          ).annotate(
            latest_msg=Max('message__modified')
          ).values(
            'message__text',
            'fields you want to fetch'
          ).order_by('-latest_msg')[:1]
```

Comment: If I use `values('message__text')`, it returns ALL the messages. I just want the LAST sent or received message.

Comment: Ideally, I want something like `values('message__text').latest()`.

Comment: well you can use limit to do that, take the latest message, check the edited answer